# Backbone JS - Model returns two results instead of one

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model

I've been fiddling around with backbone and im trying to retrieve a single result by fetching with a certain ID.

**Model:**

```
var Recipe = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'recipes',
  initialize: function() {
    this.fetch();
    console.log("A new recipe has been loaded.");
  },
});

var recipe = new Recipe({id: id});

recipe.toJSON() // Returns:
```

**Returns:**

```
Object {0: Object, id: "1"}
```

This returns the object containing all my data and a id field containing the id that im setting in `new Recipe({id: id})`.

Why is it doing that? I thought a model that was fetching with a specific ID was going to retrieve a single result. Or am I doing it wrong?

Best regards,
Jake

Comment: what is the value returned from the server?

Comment: The result returned from the server: http://pastebin.com/M4M8D3Gg - I believe that is what you mean.

Comment: hey response from the server should like thishttp://pastebin.com/xcXfCnkG

Comment: Oh okay, why is it adding the extra set of brackets?

Comment: may be you are creating multidimensional array in your backend , it has nothing to do with backbone , if you want to correct in front end you can use parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parse the data before assigning to model

```
var Recipe = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'recipes',

   parse : function(response){
   return response[0];
   },
  initialize: function() {
    this.fetch();
    console.log("A new recipe has been loaded.");
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot, it works like a charm now! Just wanted to point out that you spelled parase instead of parse.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is returning an array, when it should be returning a single JSON object for a given model. In other words, the issue is on your server: Backbone isn't processing the returned value properly, because it's expecting a JSON object instead of the array that your server is returning. Backbone typically uses collections to process arrays of JSON objects.